# Formatting cellvalue in apache poi as accounting or currency for numbers

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

The Below Code is the apache poi code for create excel cell with text value want the text value as currency.

Code :

```
    row1=   sheetNormal.createRow((short)2);
    row1.setHeight((short)(256 *1.5));
    header = row1.createCell((short)1);
    header.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(500000));
```

desired output in excel:-5,00,000

the output is shown in the form of the text.

Comment: Can you please clarify, do you want to create cell value from String or from Integer? I mean, when you are using `Integer.parseInt(value)`, this `value` should be String, but in your code you are have `500000` instead of `"500000"`.

Comment: in your example, 5 means dollars, 00 = cents, 000 = 1/1000 or a cent? Do i understand it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the output in currency, you can do something like this. Be careful, method `setStringValue(value)` accepts the value to be a `double`, but not an Integer. You can parse it from `String` to `Double` and than manipulate this value depending on the precision which you use to enter your values. This precision can be:

- entire dollars;
- cents;
- 1/1000 of a cent.

In the code below you can find all three examples (`header` is changed by `cell1`):

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("test sheet");

HSSFCellStyle currencyStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
HSSFDataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
currencyStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0.00.000"));

HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(2);
row1.setHeight((short) (256*1.5));

// Input in DOLLARS
HSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell(1);
cell1.setCellStyle(currencyStyle);
cell1.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble("5")); // output $5,00,000

// Input in CENTS
HSSFCell cell2 = row1.createCell(2);
cell2.setCellStyle(currencyStyle);
cell2.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble("499") / 100); // output $4,99,000

// Input in 1/1000 OF A CENT
HSSFCell cell3 = row1.createCell(3);
cell3.setCellStyle(currencyStyle);
cell3.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble("123456789") / 100000); // output $1 234,56,789

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("currency_data_format.xls");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you see **########** in a cell, it's because your value has too many characters. **Increase cell width**.

I can modify above code, if you give some precisions about how you enter your data. Good luck!

Comment: Can we show it as accounting.. when I work on formula cells it always shows as custom